# Getting and dealing with the Entered data in MVC - Simple

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some questions regarding my MVC learning curve

#### Goal:

I want to get the txtMHM entered text
after the btnStat is pushed and show the entered text via a label or span or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The View Model you should use (simplified):

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public string TextEntered { get ; set ; }
}
```

The View:

```
@model YourViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextEntered)
    <br />
    <input id="btnStat" type="submit" value="MHM" />
}

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TextEntered)
```

The Controller Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeLabelText(YourViewModel yourViewModel)
{
    return View(yourViewModel);
}
```

## Your Altered Code

**index.cshtml**

```
@model MVCTest1.Models.EnteredTextModel 


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextEntered) 
    <br /> 
    <input id="btnStat" type="submit" value="MHM" /> 
} 

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TextEntered)
```

**The Model**

```
namespace MVCTest1.Models 
{ 

    public class EnteredTextModel 
    { 
        public string TextEntered { get; set; } 

    } 
}
```

**The HomeController**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using MVCTest1.Models ; 

namespace MVCTest1.Controllers 
{ 
    public class HomeController : Controller 
    { 
        public ActionResult Index() 
        { 
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"; 

            return View(); 
        } 

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(EnteredTextModel theModel) 
        { 
            return View(theModel); 
        } 

        public ActionResult About() 
        { 
            return View(); 
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 shark - was literally doing just this when i saw that you'd anserwered. will still add my answer but will now adopt a different tack for variety.

Comment: Thanks, It could be really useful for me at the moment

Comment: @Jim also will be glad if I got your approach too

Comment: Sypress - alternative approach added below (untested, but should work!)

Comment: @Shark the code that I've made based on your post should have a problem, could you please look at it, and give a feedback

Comment: @Sypress You don't have an `[HttpPost]` attribute on your Action method to take the submit.

Comment: @Sypress Also, if this is all within your Index view, you need to have the Index() action methods handle this logic.  The Submit will be geared towards the view that is being submitted on, so you'll have to have an HttpPost on an Index() action method.

Comment: @Sypress See my edited post.  I have modified your code with how it should work.  This is untested, so there may be a typo/error/bug or two.  But that's the general idea.

Comment: I don't know why, but unfortunately the code seems not to work, I tested triple times even swapped my code with yours, no result

Comment: OK no problem, thanks anyway, I'll get it work at my next try

Answer (score 1):

Sypress,

Best practice would be to use a viewmodel for your action. However, at a very simple level, based on exactly what you have above, you could use the viewbag object to pass back the input value. without further ado, the frig, i mean code :):

Controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeLabelText()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeLabelText(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    ViewBag.LastNameEntered = formCollection["txtName"];
    return View();
}
```

View stuff (assumes that the view is named ChangeLabelText.cshtml of course):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ChangeLabelText";
}

<h2>ChangeLabelText</h2>
<form action="ChangeLabelText" method="post">
    <input id="txtMHM" type="text" name="txtName" value="" />
    <input id="btnStat" type="submit" value="Post"  />  
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Entered Text");
    <span id="spnEnteredText">@ViewBag.LastNameEntered </span>
</form>
```

and the above is called as such `http://localhost:xxxx/Home/ChangeLabelText` (where xxxx is the port number of your dev server)

I would add that this would NOT be the way that I would approach this to be honest, but is my direct response to your example. go for sharks' example using the viewmodel.

good luck

**[EDIT]** - I've updated my answer now that I'm at a machine, so the above should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for this man, It will help me clarifying this case and the architecture, I'll go to try and play with both of these and probably a harder example

Comment: no worries, look up 'asp.net mvc viewmodel' when next tickling google and you should find a nice variety of articles on the subject of viewmodels, they really make a HUGE difference in keeping your app purposed, especially when the domain model becomes more complex with foreign key properties etc

Comment: My friend I have 2 questions regarding your approach, I'll edit my post and give the code related to your method, please help me through this

Comment: Sypress - answer updated as requested. should work fine now. keep me posted (pun intended :))

Comment: Sorry for keep you posted :D, I mostly try to get some hints and those are enough, But in this case at first sight I have to deal with the whole idea and getting the strange parts that I couldn't find in the glanced look of some articles and chapters ordered.